# Saving html message in Outlook 2019 with .NET C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, text, outlook

Using .NET C# i want to load an Outlook html message from *.msg file, add a recipient and save it to standard draft folder.

I cannot do it properly with Outlook 2019 (not 2016 or 2013), because after saved, it turns the message body format to plain text. This happen with 2019 version only.
In the code example i first create the email and save it to draft. Until the COM Application object is instantiated the format remain html. Right after i had manually opened Outlook.exe the message has been turned to plain text. I check this with the function PrintBodyFormat. Please note this happen with Office 2019 only.

```
using Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

static void CreateMail()
{
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"C:\html_message.msg");
    mail.Recipients.Add("johndoe@foobar.com");

    Debug.WriteLine(mail.BodyFormat.ToString());
    //OUTPUT WITH ALL OUTLOOK VERSION: "olFormatHTML"

    mail.Save();
    mail.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
    mail = null;

    Outlook.NameSpace nms = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder DraftFolder = nms.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
    mail = DraftFolder.Items[1];

    Debug.WriteLine(mail.BodyFormat.ToString());
    //OUTPUT WITH ALL OUTLOOK VERSION: "olFormatHTML"

    mail.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
    mail = null;
    app.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(DraftFolder);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nms);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
}

//Run this after manually opened Outlook.exe 
static void PrintBodyFormat()
{
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace nms = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder DraftFolder = nms.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
    Outlook.MailItem mail = DraftFolder.Items[1];

    Debug.WriteLine(mail.BodyFormat.ToString());
    //OUTPUT WITH OUTLOOK 2016 OR EARLIER: "olFormatHTML"
    //OUTPUT WITH OUTLOOK 2019: "olFormatPlain"

    app.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(DraftFolder);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nms);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mail.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);` - you never showed the inspector, so there is no reason to close it.

Also, `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` won't do much since you never release the `Recipients` collection and the `Recipient` object returned by `Recipients.Add` - both of them keep a reference to the parent message, and you end up with two implicit variables that you never release.

Do not use `DraftFolder.Items[1]` - save the value of `MailItem.EntryID` in a variable after calling `Save`, then use it to reopen the message using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, but this simple piece of code has the only purpose to show that Outlook 2019 turn the saved mail to plain text without any reason. Can you figure out why?

Comment: Does it still happen if you get rid of mail.Close?

Comment: Yes it does. I've tried to Move() the MailItem instead of save it and it is just the same. Again this happen with Outlook 2019 only. Outlook 2016 works fine.